# How does the console.log determine that an object is a custom (not built-in) class or instance of custom class?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let me explain my question with an example.
Let's define some class and its instance:

```
class MyClass {
  a() { return 1 }
}

const myInstance = new MyClass()
```

`console.log(MyClass)` returns "**[class MyClass]**".

`console.log(myInstance)` returns "**MyClass {}**"

Where does console.log get these values from?
I tried several ways to get it, but they return different:

**For the class:**

```
console.log(MyClass.toString()) // class MyClass {
                                //   a() { return 1; }
                                // }

console.log(MyClass.constuctor.toString()) // function Function() { [native code] }

console.log(MyClass.constuctor.name) // Function

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(MyClass)) // [object Function]

console.log(MyClass[Symbol.toStringTag]) // undefined
```

**And for the instance:**

```
console.log(myInstance.toString()) // [object Object]

console.log(myInstance.constuctor.toString()) // class MyClass {
                                              //   a() { return 1; }
                                              // }


console.log(myInstance.constuctor.name) // MyClass

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(MyClass)) // [object Object]

console.log(myInstance[Symbol.toStringTag]) // undefined
```

So, let's imagine that my goal is to write a function that returns "class MyClass" when passing a class, and returns "MyClass {}" when passing an instance. How can I do this? Of course, similar data is in the results of the examples above and I can use it. However, I suspect there is a much simpler solution.

Comment: See [`Symbol.toStringTag`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag). `MyClass.constuctor` has nothing to do with the class. `MyClass` is the constructor itself.

Comment: Not sure to understand. You are deciding. myInstance = new MyClass() means "create an instance of class MyClass and assign it to myinstance". Aa class and an instance of that class are two different things

Comment: I tried it, but MyClass[Symbol.toStringTag] and myInstance[Symbol.toStringTag] are undefined.
My goal is to write a function that returns "class MyClass" when passing a class, and returns "MyClass {}" when passing an instance. How can I do this? Of course, similar data is in the results of the examples above and I can use it. However, I suspect there is a much simpler solution.

Comment: It's Node.js, not a browser. But Node.js using the same v8 engine as Chromium browser.

Comment: Just check the .prototype, instance will return undefined, class will return object. .constructor.name will return "MyClass" for the instance and Function for the class

Comment: Thank you, of course I can do that. But it seems to me that these values are already contained in the class and in the instance, it is unlikely that the console.log constructs them in this way.

Comment: I doubt you can affect much on the console output. Console analyzes the logged object in its own way. You can set `Symbol.toStringTag`, usually it's read with `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)`, see more information at the MDN page Sebastian has linked to.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to change the console output, but reproduce its behavior

Comment: Console can access an object much deeper than ECMAScript language features, all the information is not available in JS. Ex. a class is actually a function. You can [create your own](https://jsfiddle.net/wua2emk7/) toString/valueOf accessors for objects, and use those in your program (they're still not logged, though).

Comment: Thanks. This is a really interesting solution. The only doubt is purely architectural: monkey-patching is frowned upon in Javascript, so it's best to avoid chaning built-in language objects.

Comment: It's not monkey-patching (the prototype is not touched), it's just shadowing the method in instances and in the class. This is commonly used practice, which is often used when you're creating objects behaving like instances of `Date`.

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, your suggestion is the best in my opinion.

Comment: The nodejs output still looks weird, I don't have a nodejs at hands right now, but `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(MyClass));` returns `[object Function]` in Chromium browser console. There seems to be some differencies between the consoles.